DOI regex matching while excluding ending markers
I am trying to extract DOI from a URL using a regex. Below are my test cases:

url/bar match nothing
url/10.1010/abc123 match 10.1010/abc123
url/10.1010/2024.01.01.123v1 match 10.1010/2024.01.01.123v1
url/10.1010/2024.01.01.123v1.full-text match 10.1010/2024.01.01.123v1
url/10.1010/123456-2/some-long-extra-words match foo/10.1010/123456-2
url/10.1010/123-456/abc123/meta match 10.1010/123-456/abc123
url/10.1010/abc123abc.pdf match 10.1010/abc123abc
url/10.1010/a.bc.2024.01.001 match 10.1010/a.bc.2024.01.001
url/10.1010/abc.2024.00001 match 10.1010/abc.2024.00001
url/10.1010/abc-2024-abc123-v1 match 10.1010/abc-2024-abc123-v1
url/10.1010/2024.01.01.123.full.pdf match 10.1010/2024.01.01.123
url/10.1010/(ABC)123-123(123)123:1<123::abc-1a>1.0.ab;2-a match 10.1010/(ABC)123-123(123)123:1<123::abc-1a>1.0.ab;2-a

Following https://www.crossref.org/blog/dois-and-matching-regular-expressions/ (thanks to this and this answer) brings me to 10.\d{4,9}\/[-.;():\w]+: https://regex101.com/r/pzzOvB/6
However, it's not properly:

Excluding .full-text
Excluding /meta while matching abc123

How can I apply lookahead/lookbehind to solve this problem?

The rules are so obscure... Try https://regex101.com/r/pzzOvB/2

Can you clarify the rules? If the rule is that there must exist at least one digit in each token, have a look at this idea: \b10\.\d{4,9}\/(?:[\/)(.;:-]?[a-z]*\d\w*)+

Thank you both for submitting possible solutions! I have added a few cases that I learned about this morning. @bobblebubble I am not sure of the exact rules to be honest, it's a DOI in a URL

If you can't define the rules, the only way is to start with a generous pattern and add exclusions as soon as one does not fit or conditions to stop. For example after 10.1010/ start with matching all non-whitespaces \S and require at least one digit. After this part continue matching \S and stop at .pdf or /meta by use of a negative lookahead, something like this demo.

I think you need to create some very specific rules around exclusions like ".full-text", and handle those separately from your regex. Technically that string is still a valid DOI, so you don't have a concrete way to test for that outside of a lookup of disallowed phrases in your results. The rules set forth here are helpful in understanding the DOIs themselves, but they are vague enough that parsing from a URL with regex alone is borderline impossible https://support.datacite.org/docs/doi-basics

It also explicitly states: "These reserved characters should not be included in a DOI suffix: ; | / | ? | : | @ | & | = | + | $ | ,"  which makes me think that last example in your list is erroneous

I got that last example from here: https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0177(200006)218:2%3C235::AID-DVDY2%3E3.0.CO;2-G. I guess that DOI is actually invalid. So far the best regex I have is: 10.\d{4,9}(?:[\/\.][a-z-().]*(?:.[\d]+[-<>;():\w]*)+)+
